# Trouble with function parameters/calling functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I am having difficulty implementing different functions in my program due to their types of parameters. I am in the process of writing a program that reads three sequences of letters from an input file, stores these sequences in separate arrays, and then compares the arrays and prints the percentage of overlap. I am using the following functions in my program:

1. The function `read_DNA(char sequence[])` that reads a DNA sequence from input,
   stores it in the array `sequence[]`, and returns the number of letters read, as an `int`.
2. The function `compare_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n)` that stores in the array `seq3[]` the comparison sequence of the two DNA sequences stored in `seq1 []` and `seq2[]`. The length of these DNA sequences is assumed to be `n`. The function returns, as a `double`, the percentage of overlap between the two DNA sequences.
3. The function `print_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n)`
   that prints to output the DNA sequences stored in `seq1[]` and `seq2[]`, as well as their
   comparison sequence stored in `seq3[]`, according to the rules explained above. The length
   of all these sequences is assumed to be `n`. The function does not return a value.

How can I access the actual letters stored in each sequence if the function `read_DNA()` only returns the number of letters read? I am unsure of how to call `read_DNA()` in my function `compare_DNA()` and compare the actual letters of each array.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `read_DNA(char sequence[])` is a *call by reference*. Therefore, it wont be a problem

Comment: C does not support call by reference. It's passing an array variable, which in C works similarly to a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this is simpler than you thought.

Inside `read_DNA`, for example, if `i` was an integer representing the index of the letter, you would use `sequence[i]` as the parameter name is `sequence`.

Inside `compare_DNA` and `print_DNA` you would use `seq1[i]`, `seq2[i]` etc.

If you called `read_DNA` like this:

```
/* needs to be big enough for the sequence to be read in */
char my_sequence[1234]; 

int len;
len = read_DNA (my_sequence);
```

then you might refer to it by `my_sequence[i]`, for instance:

```
int i;
for (i=0 ; i<len; i++)
{
    char c = my_sequence[i];
    /* do something with c */
}
```

As an example, here's how you might write your compare function (untested):

```
double
compare_DNA(char seq1[], char seq2[], char seq3[], int n)
{
    int i;
    int match = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (seq1[i] == seq2[i])
        {
            /* record the matching letter in seq3 */
            seq3[i] = seq1[i];
            match++;
        }
        else
        {
            /* record a '?' in seq3 */
            seq3[i] = '?';
        }
    }
    return (double)match * 100.0 / (double)n;
}
```

Note not knowing anything about how one compare's DNA, I've made it make `seq3` containing the matching letter if the letters match, or a `?` if they do not match.

Comment: I see what you're saying... Here is what I have for read_DNA:        int read_DNA (char sequence[])
{
  int i, count=0;

  /*reads DNA sequence from input, stores it in an array, and returns the # of letters read as an int */

  input=fopen("dna_input.dat", "r");

  for(i=0; i<MAX_IN_LENGTH; i++) {
    if (fscanf (input, "%c", &sequence[i]) != EOF)
      if (sequence[i] == '\n')
        {
          i++;
          break;
        }
  }
  return i;
}

Comment: I am still confused about how to compare each sequence in compare_DNA

Comment: I've added an example of how one might do that.

Comment: Thank you, that clarified a lot.